# Open source library to convert DOC and other MS-Office files to image(s)

Tags: c++, image, ms-office, documents

Can you recommend an open source library (C or C++) to convert MS Office files into a set of images?

I am evaluating ImageMagick and while it does support PDF files, it does not work with MS Office files.

Comment: what format do you need to read?

Answer (score 1):

This library is quite popular and used by abiword (gnome) and kword (kde): [wvWare](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Hm I've seen that OpenOffice does a good job on "translating" Word to whatever, so how about installing OpenOffice and maybe using it's UNO model from C++ to solve that problem?